# Tweaking table size with column separation

Tags: tables

I have a large table which is very slightly wider (around 1cm) than my text width and I want to squash it up slightly so that it fits. Rotating it or resizing the text was undesirable in this context. So far I have managed to get the following to produce the desired behaviour:

```
\begin{table}[t]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c c c c c}
        % content
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

A brief explanation: line 2 slightly reduces the space between all the columns to get my table slightly less than the text width; the `{\textwidth}` of line 3 expands the table to be exactly the width of the text; then the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` adds in a tiny extra space to shift the columns over slightly so they correctly line up with the right edge of the table.

So I have a few questions about this:

Firstly, does line 2 enclosed in the table environment change the column separation for just this table, or will it affect other tables in my document? I only want this table to be affected.

Second, is there a better way to go about this? Ideally I'd have something which automatically expanded or contracted the column separations/widths to achieve a specified table width.

Comment: Answer to the first question is `Yes`, ie `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` enclosed in the `table` environment change the column separation for just this table.

Comment: Does [that](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Controlling_table_size) help?

Comment: @vaettchen Not quite. The code ````\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{object}```` resizes the object, including the text. For small tweaks I could probably get away with it, depending on how picky I was being about the text size. Ideally I'd like this to be unchanged though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{table}[t]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c c c c c}
        % content
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

`\setlength` is a local setting so it is scoped by the surrounding `table` environment so only affects this one table. Note however that `@` *removes* the tabcolsep where it is used, so if the table is tight there is no separation at all between columns one and two. You could use the `!` type from the `array` package which is similar to`@` but does not remove the default space, or the normal idiom is

```
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c c c c c c c@{}}
```

So that the column padding is moved from *both* outer edges not between columns of the table.